# Change UISwipeGestureRecognizer direction in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a function handleSwipe that is connected to an image view (imageContainer3), so when user swipes the image, an animations happens. Here is the function.

```
@IBAction func handleSwipe(recognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    self.imageContainer3.center = CGPoint(x:29, y:264)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.2, animations: {
        self.imageContainer3.center = CGPoint(x:29, y:157)

    })

}
```

Problem is that by default this function only triggers when user swipes to the right. I would like it not to recognize right swipe, but left swipe. Do you know how I can achieve desired result in swift ? Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select the swipe gesture recognizer in your storyboard, you can change the swipe direction in the Attributes Inspector:

[image]

Comment: thanks, I didn't expected to be able to manage this without programatic intervention

Comment: There's a lot in that attributes panel - make sure you explore the options for different UI types. The attributes are grouped by class inheritance, so in the one above you have the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` attributes first, then the ones that are a part of `UIGestureRecognizer`.